# Krita export image create white lines D:

Tags: export, krita

I am new to krita and im running in a weird problem that I don't know how to fix.

I just finished and drawing and wanted to export it to post it, but whenever I post my drawing, the exported drawing doesn't look like what I did in krita, the export adds ugly white lines in the middle of my drawing :

Here is a zoomed screenshot of my drawing in krita :
[image]

And here is a zoomed screenshot of my drawing once it has been exported by krita :
[image]

Note how there are ugly white lines in between the colors on the second image

And now that I look at the two images side-by-side, I also notice a slight shift in the colors, the red looks more vibrant on the first image, but maybe that's just an illusion caused by the white lines.

I tried exporting in jpeg, png, jpg, and the everytime, the compression was set to 1/the quality was set to 100%. I have no idea why this thing happens and I don't have extensive knowledge of how images are encoded in function of the formats so I don't know how I could fix it D:

Thanks in advance for your help :D

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. You can't zoom in on raster images and expect them to look good. View the image at 100%.  Check your computer does not have some system zoom setting.

Comment: Is there no way to make image look good when zoomed ? Krita manages to do it as I've shown, and I don't see such bugs when I'm watching other people's images on deviantart

Comment: You'd need to start with a higher resolution image in Krita (i.e. one which has more pixels, a larger canvas) if your intention is to be able to zoom in on an image, but zooming beyond 100% will always result in problems. That's the nature of raster images.

Comment: How the application that does zooming is out of your hands, krita has no control over this. Canging the image format is not of much more use either.

Comment: This image was a 2000/2500, I thought I was going way overboard with my image resolution, but I guess I'm gonna go 999999999/99999999999 next time :/

Comment: The image may be big, but you still can't zoom in more than 100% and still expect it to look good.  Raster images always have this limitation. It has nothing to do with Krita per se. If you want to be able to zoom without degradation in quality, perhaps have a look at using vector image editing software instead. Try Inkscape, it's also free and Open Source like Krita.

Comment: Here's [a vector version](https://svgshare.com/i/QrB.svg) of part of your illustration - try zooming in on it.

Comment: I didn't came back here for a while because I actually solved my problem. The way I did was to copy-paste my image in a new krita image, but something like 10 times bigger, and then when re-exporting, the problems were gone.                  Billy, I knew about inkscape, but I am afraid that vectorisation of images trough inkscape might loose details of the images. On this particular drawing with plain colors, it would'nt be a problem, but imagine a drawing with a gradient. The gradient would'nt stay in the vector version, would it ?